# ajax Loader BEFORE page load

Tags: jquery

I want to show an ajax loader before the page is loaded. At the moment it will only show when the page is loaded, but the 2 seconds before that I only see a white screen.

Is it possible to have this ajax loader instead of the white screen? It seems that it loads when the page is loaded but not before and I've tried multiple jQuery codes, on document ready, on load, etc.. I've also included a video example: https://streamable.com/5n8n4k

My jQuery code:

```js
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery('body').append("<div class='ui-loader-background'> </div>");
  jQuery("#loadingDiv").css("display","block");
  jQuery(".ui-loader-background").show();
});
```

my HTML code:

```html
<div id="loadingDiv">
<div class="cssload-thecube">
    <div class="cssload-cube cssload-c1"></div>
    <div class="cssload-cube cssload-c2"></div>
    <div class="cssload-cube cssload-c4"></div>
    <div class="cssload-cube cssload-c3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `jQuery(window).on("load", ...`

Comment: Hello Phil,

Thank you for your feedback, this indeed opens the loader but only after the page is loaded not before. I still see the white screen before the ajax loader like in my video example..